# Why does python script run via terminal but does not via crontab?

Tags: python, cron

I am grateful for any advice.

That is my python script:

```
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
import time

time = time.localtime()
hourMinSec = (str(time.tm_hour) +":"+ str(time.tm_min) +":"+ str(time.tm_sec))

mouse = Controller()
print (mouse.position)
print (hourMinSec)

with open('/home/panda/desktop/mouseProg.log', 'a') as f:
    f.write(str(mouse.position) + "\n")
    f.write(str(hourMinSec) + "\n")
```

That obviously gives me the mouse position and the time.

> (1234,234)
>
> 12:23:34

Runs perfectly fine in linux terminal.

But when I try to run it via crontab I get that:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/panda/PycharmProjects/Giraffe/maus.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pynput/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from . import keyboard
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pynput/keyboard/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from ._xorg import KeyCode, Key, Controller, Listener
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pynput/keyboard/_xorg.py", line 39, in <module>
    from pynput._util.xorg import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pynput/_util/xorg.py", line 40, in <module>
    _check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pynput/_util/xorg.py", line 38, in _check
    display = Xlib.display.Display()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 89, in __init__
    self.display = _BaseDisplay(display)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 71, in __init__
    protocol_display.Display.__init__(self, *args, **keys)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/Xlib/protocol/display.py", line 84, in __init__
    name, protocol, host, displayno, screenno = connect.get_display(display)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/Xlib/support/connect.py", line 73, in get_display
    return mod.get_display(display)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/Xlib/support/unix_connect.py", line 76, in get_display
    raise error.DisplayNameError(display)
Xlib.error.DisplayNameError: Bad display name ""
```

It seems that the problem is linked to

```
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
```

sice when I comment it out (and the correlated lines) it runs fine even via crontab.

Comment: Programs run from cron generally can't access the GUI.

Comment: Thank you guys. Especially @MikeScotty.
 
It did, indeed!!  `DISPLAY=":0" ` was the solution

Comment: Hi guys, I need to run a python script using pynput module using crontab, is that possible? This script runs perfectly if I execute it from terminal. Thak's in advance!